# Breaking 64 figures into a set of subplots

Tags: matlab

i'm constructing 64 images from a data set.

i have to subplot them by (4*4) into 4 figures.

I just managed to subplot them as 64 in a single figure.

Any idea how to make it.

```
clear all, 
close all;
clc;
load('ee.mat')


for i=1:64
 s=ee(:,:,i);
 s(:,:,i)=abs(s);
 subplot(8,8,i); imshow(s(:,:,i),[]),title(['reconstructed Image' num2str(i)])
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by _i have to subplot them by (4*4) into 4._? Could you please explain this in more detail?

Comment: Now I have 64 figures in one same window. I want them as 4*4 in 4 windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use two loops.

This is just for generating ee since I don't have ee.mat

```
cm = imread('cameraman.tif');
ee = repmat(cm, 1,1,64);
```

And here are the two loops

```
counter = 1;
for nfigure=1:4
    figure
    for nimg = 1:16
        subplot(4,4,nimg); 
        imshow(abs(ee(:,:,counter)));
        title(['reconstructed Image' num2str(counter)]);

        counter = counter + 1;
    end
end
```

Note that I have removed the lines

```
s=ee(:,:,i);
s(:,:,i)=abs(s);
```

Comment: heii Patrick
gracious for your time ,
the question (4*4)*4 is achieved.
but im getting black images. 
any idea how to sort it.

Comment: No idea. For this, one needs to know your `ee`. Might be better suited for a new question.